# git rebase squash finds merge conflicts despite fast forward

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I have a feature branch with many trial-and-error commits and I want to combine all my changes into a single commit before merging to `develop`.  I'm using `git rebase -i` to do this but getting surprising results.

My feature branch is fully ahead of `develop` and `develop` is not ahead of my feature branch.  As a pre-merge step, I created a new branch `feature-squash` from the `develop` branch, checked out my feature branch, and then ran `git rebase -i feature-squash`.  In the editor screen, I left `pick` for the first commit but for every commit after it I chose to `squash`.  Then I committed the rebase instructions.

The idea is that after this is done, the repo contents for `feature-squash` should be completely identical to the original feature branch, but only a single commit ahead of `develop`.

To my surprise there were multiple points during the rebase when merge conflicts were found.  Each time I resolved the conflict in favor of "theirs" (choosing the alternative *not* on `HEAD`), `git add`ed the resolved files, and ran `git rebase --continue`.  This happened multiple times, but not for every commit, only some of them.

I don't understand why there are merge conflicts in this situation, when all commits from `develop` had already been merged into my feature branch and are therefore in the branch history.  What are my commits conflicting with?  Is `squash` not the right choice for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The conflicts are showing up _probably_ because you have merges in your feature branch. Anyway, if you intend to turn all the work into a single commit it's easier to run a merge with `develop` first, then do `git reset --soft develop; git commit -m "everything in a single shot"`.